# Chrome Extension: How to detect when user initiates download when another extension hijacks the download process

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

What I want to do is

1- User initiates download by clicking a link with download attribute `<a ... download="" /a>`

2- Browser shows spinner on the tab that indicates a connection is made

3- The spinner stops turning and site icon is displayed again while the other extension(internet download manager extension)` opens a download prompt in the app.

I would like to know when step 3 happens and close that tab.

Normally using `chrome.downloads.onCreated` works but since there is another extension(internet download manager extension) which takes the download and directs it to its app, my extension is not notified when downloads are initiated. I realized that they also use `chrome.webRequest` too but I don't know if its relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I could solve this with polling the status of the tab.

```js
// content.ts
// Telling background to start polling
chrome.runtime.sendMessage("POLL")
```

```js
//background.ts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(async(message, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (message !== "POLL") return

    const tab = sender.tab!
    if (!tab) return
    const id = tab.id 
    if (!id) return 

    // Doesnt return until the inner condition returns a truthy result
    await tryGettingAsync(async() => {
        const upToDateTab = await chrome.tabs.get(id)
        return upToDateTab?.status === "complete"
    }, INTERVAL, MAX_TIME / INTERVAL)
    chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id!)
})

export const tryGettingAsync = async<T>(cb: () => Promise<T | undefined | null>, ms: number, attempts = Infinity) => {
    let count = 0;
    let result = await cb()
    count++
    while (!result && count <= attempts) {
      await sleep(ms);
      result = await cb();
      count++
    }
    return result;
}
```